# InvalidOperationException when adding a second file name to SQLite

Tags: c#

When adding a second or third file to SQLite in the below code I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled.
>   An unhandled expection of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occured in System.Data.SQLite.dll

This is my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  con.Open();  

  string name = textBox1.Text;
  SQLiteCommand kom = con.CreateCommand();
  kom.CommandText = "insert into test(name) values('" + name + "'')";
  kom.ExecuteNonQuery();
  textBox1.Clear();

  con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you forgot  _Space_ between **test** & **(name)**

Comment: Yes i forget it.Thanks very much.It helps second file adding.
But third time isnot adding file in database.shows same error

Comment: It doesnot helps.same error occured

Comment: @Magnificent_Dubracer Can you please add **stack trace**

Comment: (From Review): I changed the title and reformatted the question. Please try to properly format your question in the future.

Comment: @Magnificent_Dubracer I Can not see the **full stack trace** but you may have a table with some **UniqueKey Constrain** and _duplicate key_ error  or **primery key** or **none null-able** and don't fill that field . we need to see **full stack trace** and if not help we need to see your **table field**

Comment: A will add new question page and i add there all code projects. - Ali Sheikh Nezami. I did not add project code in the commant.

Comment: @Ali Sheikh Nezami  Do you have a mail? I want to send my code project to Your mail.can u give me your mail?

Comment: @Magnificent_Dubracer farheekhte@gmail.com

Comment: @ Ali Sheikh Nezami There I was a new user .I was send my project code your gmail.look my code project and

Comment: Thanks for everybody helps to me.I will find my error. I didnt usin Pooling = true; operator in the connection.have there any operators i can use sqllite connection?

Comment: Good Luck Boy That's it try try try ...

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
kom.CommandText = "insert into test(name) values('" + name + "'')";
```

With:

```
kom.CommandText = "insert into test(name) values('" + name + "')";
```

There are two single quotes at the end of the column value instead of one.

Comment: I delete the one quote nothing changed.

Comment: first data was added in database.but secont data was not.i'll add all project code now...

Comment: Do you have a mail? I want to send my code project to 
 Your mail.can u give me your mail?